# Java textfield decimal validation

Tags: java, swing, format, double, decimal

How can I validate user input contain only 5 digits with 2 decimal. I am using below code to check 5 digits, but how to check 2 decimal.

```
if (!id.equals("")) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(id);
            if (id.length() <= 5) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may be interested in [JFormattedTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(id.matches("\\d{5}\\.\\d{2}"))
    return true;
return false;
```

Comment: Well except he wants "up to 5," not "exactly five."

Answer (score 5):

The [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class will help you significantly with this. You can check that the user-input can be parsed according to a specific pattern.

The [commons-validator library wraps this up in a convenient method call](http://commons.apache.org/validator/api-1.3.1/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DoubleValidator.html#validate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29).

Answer (score 3):

Any validation in Swing can be performed using an InputVerifier.

1. First create your own input verifier

   > ```
   > public class MyInputVerifier extends InputVerifier {
   >     public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
   >         String text = ((JTextField) input).getText();
   >         try {
   >             BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(text);
   >             return (value.scale() <= Math.abs(2)); 
   >         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   >             return false;
   >         }
   >     }
   > }
   > ```
2. Then assign an instance of that class to your text field. (In fact any JComponent can be verified)

myTextField.setInputVerifier(new MyInputVerifier());
Of course you can also use an anonymous inner class, but if the validator is to be used on other components, too, a normal class is better.

Also have a look at the SDK documentation: JComponent#setInputVerifier.